# Criteria not working in case Statement, But the same criteria does work in my where clause

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause

I am working with Microsoft SSMS database, trying to get monthly volume of correct, wrong, late, missing. when i use a case statement, I am missing a record

```
    ,convert(float,sum(case when [field1] = 'blue' 
        and [timestampfield1] is not null
        and json_value([json_error_field1],'$.error1') is null
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_correct'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when [field1] = 'blue'
        and json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'late'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_late'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when [field1] = 'blue'
        and json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'wrong'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_wrong'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when [field1] = 'blue'
        and json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'missing'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_missing'
from 
    [DB]..[table]
where
    [datefield] between cast(@start_date as date) and cast(@end_date as date)
```

since [field1] is consistent error1, i applied it to the where criteria and it worked. the problem is i have 4 error scenarios that have different [field1] criteria (ie [field1] = 'red'. here is the same code but with [field1] criteria in where-clause

```
    ,convert(float,sum(case when [timestampfield1] is not null
        and json_value([json_error_field1],'$.error1') is null
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_correct'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'late'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_late'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'wrong'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_wrong'

    ,convert(float,sum(case when json_value([json_error_field],'$.error1') = 'missing'
        then 1 else 0 end))as 'error1_missing'
from 
    [DB]..[table]
where
    [datefield] between cast(@start_date as date) and cast(@end_date as date) 
    and [field1] = 'blue'
```

for reference [field1] is a nvarchar(4), null. any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: to clarify, only the 'late' sum is off by one, the rest are working as expected.

Comment: turns out the field1 changed from blue to red causing my output to be different, this can be closed